# Ajax and Php form data save to MS SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, ajax

UPDATE: I tried to do everything as example created table "grid" but still same effect, can't create new lines.

I found this tool in internet [a link](http://www.asif18.com/21/php/simple-on-click-edit-in-jquery-ajax-php-simple-php-data-grid/success/#4471) where table data is selected and then you can manipulate with it. The only thing that is wrong is that I can't update or insert new values to the table. But I can delete them. Maybe I'm missing something but all i did was change item names.

```
case "addnew":
    $user = isset($_POST['user']) ? mssql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']) : '';
    mssql_query("INSERT INTO workflow (user) VALUES ('$user')");
break;
```

And yes, I also change from `MYSQL` to `MSSQL`, but if delete works and all data is fetched, why can't I update or insert?

Comment: It would be really helpful to add the log output of your program as well as your database (if there is no helpful output, try to produce it, e.g. increase the log level of MSSQL). Also, try the INSERT statement in your code directly in MSSQL using the same user you are using with your code.

Comment: @Risadinha i just tried 'mssql_query("INSERT INTO workflow (user) VALUES ('kobolt')");' and it didn't work. I think something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the code nut with the permission level. The user which you used to login may not be having the INSERT/UPDATE privilege. USe grant query to grant the privilege https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html.

Comment: well i use the same user to login with SQL Server Management Studio and i can INSERT/UPDATE so the problem i think something else.